# Как скрыть тексты городов в карте Openlayers используя OSM тайлы?

Tags: openstreetmap, openlayers

Вывел карту через OpenLayerMap.

```
let urlOSMServerTile = "http://localhost:8087" + "/tile/{z}/{x}/{y}.png";

let baseLayer = new TileLayer({
  source: new OSM(
    {
      url: urlOSMServerTile,
      crossOrigin: null,
      params: {
        transparent: 'true',
        numZoomLevels: 19
      }
    }
  )
});

    map = new OpenLayerMap({
          target: 'M1-map',
          layers: [
            baseLayer
          ]
        });
```

Но там выводятся названия городов, какие то треугольники, дороги и.т.д.
А как управлять тем, что нужно отобразить? Например скрыть названия всех городов или указать у них при каком zoom они должны появляться?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]